# Touchpad support for SublimeText 3

Tags: touchpad, touchscreen, sublime-text-3, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I love SublimeText 3, but the only thing stopping me from buying a licence is the lack of decent touch(pad) support. I often work on the road, and some decent swipe/scroll support on touch and touchpad would be nice. Am I missing something in the settings, or is this simply not implemented in ST3?

Devices that I know have this problem. If you have this problem as well and your device is not listed, please leave a comment.

- Surface Pro 3
- Surface Pro 2
- Dell XPS 13(z)
- Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro

This question seems to attract quite some attention still, and I'm sorry to inform that the developers are *aware* of this problem but a fix hasn't been announced. If you have a GitHub account, you can reply [to this issue thread](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/691). Reply *+1 [your device]* so the developers know which devices have this problem. You can also simply create a new GitHub account.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You should be able to scroll using your touchpad. What other functions are you looking for?

Comment: @MattDMo In any programme, I can scroll by moving two fingers up and down the touchpad, but that doesn't work in Sublime. Also scrolling by touch (swiping on a touchscreen) doesn't work.

Comment: For those who are curious: since the devs over at Sublime don't seem to care about this issue, I swapped it out for the new editor by GitHub: [Atom](https://atom.io/). This programme doesn't have this issue! Do note, though, that it has only recently reached version 1.0, so it's got a lot of things that not to be fixed, *but* you can use it just fine. Pros: it's free, as open-source as it can be, and founded y the guys at GitHub - so it promises to be the best open-source editor yet!

Comment: I'm using a Lenovo T450, and surface pro 4 and the two finger touch pad scrolling is working now. Maybe it has been resolved.

Touch screen scrolling is not working in my case though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been fixed by the developers.https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/691#issuecomment-476336332

Answer (score 1):

According to the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/691), the problem has been solved last year in build 3136. Current build is 3207, so updating Sublime Text to latest stable version should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it only works in sublime if you hide the menu at the top, or if you go into fullscreen / distraction free mode.